# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In one of my maven project dependency graph of hibernate-core is as follows:

```
    [INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.10.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile - version managed from 3.3.2.Final; omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
    +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.10.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO] | +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
```

I am getting error as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.salesforce.sconems.abstractions.SconeApp.run(SconeApp.java:118)
    at com.salesforce.sconems.abstractions.SconeApp.run(SconeApp.java:163)
    at com.salesforce.tm.ThreatmodelServiceService.main(ThreatmodelServiceService.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:836)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Regarding same, I followed this posts: [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568835/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-table) and [NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index). I am not getting any clue regarding how to fix this.

Comment: Is there another jpa dependency on the classpath? Or any other jar that conains a class javax.persistence.Table?

Comment: Yes @GreyFairer I have. I have org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile and javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile. I have updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. This was because of adding Java EE6 jar as an external dependency through Intellij, which I had done while setting up the project. As soon as I removed this, it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the dependencies, you will probably find something like:

```
spring-data-jpa:2.2.4.RELEASE 
-> org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.17.Final(optional) 
-> org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
```

So that's probably the one with the older javax.persistence.Table class.

I'm not sure if Spring Data is ready for JPA 2.2.

If you look at the pom.xml for [spring-data-jpa:2.2.4.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.2.4.RELEASE/pom.xml), it depends on hibernate 5.2.17.Final, and they haven't updated yet.

So I would stick to the hibernate 5.2.x series.

Comment: Yeah @GryFairer, I am trying to get rid of this dependency org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile, but I am not able to even after putting in exclusion block inside hibernate-core in pom.xml

Comment: Yeah, exclusion blocks are terrible to work with.
But I think if you lower the version for hibernate to 5.2.17.Final or 5.2.18.Final, everything should work without needing exclusion blocks.